# Make vb.net program accessible for multiple users and computers

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Can someone tell me how to make my vb.net program accessible by multiple users from different computers at a time. My program has forms that will take input and save in MySQL. If multiple users from different computers fill forms it should be saved into mysql.
I am using VS 2013.

Please give me an idea about how to make this.

Answer (score 2):

As an idea, you could make two programs , 1 called **Server** found on your personal **PC** and the other is called **Client** on every other user's **PC**, when client makes a change it calls a function on servers PC using **.Net Remoting** technology, and the server makes the appropriate changes to the **MySQL**.

So every change would affect one **Database** over WAN , and you can add event to each change that will **invoke** all users to update information.

hope to help :)

Comment: Microsoft recommends using WCF over .NET Remoting now.

Comment: @JosephDSurgeon its true right now i am trying to learn WCF but stock with sessions in wsHttpBinding LoL

Comment: I have been using it for years if you need help let me know :)

Comment: @JosephDSurgeon actually yes , i am making an WCF service which have to call a function that uses session, i used wsbinding with aspnetcompabillity enabled and transport security to basic, message security as username and to establishSecurityContext set to true still when the function is called the session is Nothing.
my service have Sessionmode set to Required. but still no sessions

Comment: try this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040(v=vs.110).aspx I have to see the config. I am sure this will help. if it doesn't try using signalR which is really good for server to client or client to server sessions and real time communication. It even allows to the server to invoke client events